# How to close the window in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, ide, window, webstorm, text-editor

When I press the key combination `ctrl + shift + f` an additional search box opens in WebStorm, but I don't understand how to close it then

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The window is kept open because it is pinned. Click the highlighted "pin" button in the very top right, and then click anywhere outside of the window to close it.

Answer (score 2):

Answer with unpin will solve the issue. There's one more way -> Click anywhere on the popup window open due to ctrl+shift+f to focus on that window. Then click `Esc` button. The search popup window will get closed